# How to send e-mail from localhost with phpmailer in Android by using Volley library?

Tags: php, android, api, android-volley, phpmailer

There is a Login and Registration system in my app. I want to add "Forgot Password" field. If any user forget his password, user can get his password by clicking "Forgot Password" button. If registered user click "Forgot Password" button, an email will be sent to his given email address with a code.

1. Here is my `Java` code:

   ```
          public class ForgotPassword extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

       EditText et_email, et_name, et_dob;
       String email, name, dob;
       Button recoverPassword;

      @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);


   et_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_rp_email);
   et_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_rp_name);
   et_dob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_rp_bd);

   recoverPassword = (Button)findViewById(R.id.recoverPassword);

   recoverPassword.setOnClickListener(this);


      }

         private void recoverPassword() {
   email = et_email.getText().toString().trim();
   name = et_name.getText().toString().trim();
   dob = et_dob.getText().toString().trim();




   StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.FORGOTPASSWORD_URL,
           new Response.Listener<String>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(String response) {
                   if(response.trim().equals("success")){
                       sendEmail();

                       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ForgotPassword.this.getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                       //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
                       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                       //Adding values to editor
                       editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
                       editor.putString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, email);


                       //Saving values to editor
                       editor.commit();


                   }else{
                       Toast.makeText(ForgotPassword.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
               }
           },
           new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   Toast.makeText(ForgotPassword.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
               }
           }){
       @Override
       protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
           Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
           map.put(Config.KEY_EMAIL,email);
           map.put(Config.KEY_NAME,name);
           map.put(Config.KEY_DOB,dob);
           return map;
       }
   };

   RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
   requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
      }


         @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

   AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Would you like to exit?");

   alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
           Toast.makeText(ForgotPassword.this, "You clicked yes button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           //Getting editor
           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
           editor.clear();
           editor.commit();
           Intent intent = new Intent(ForgotPassword.this, Login.class);
           startActivity(intent);

       }
   });

   alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           Toast.makeText(ForgotPassword.this, "You clicked No button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           //finish();
       }
   });

   AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
   alertDialog.show();
      }

      private void sendEmail(){

   Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
   emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + "recipient@example.com"));
   emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My email's subject");
   emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My email's body");

   try {
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using..."));
   } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
       Toast.makeText(ForgotPassword.this, "No email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

     }


      @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
   if (v == recoverPassword){
       recoverPassword();
   }

       }

        }
   ```
2. Here is my PHP code:

   ```
     <?php 
     require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
     $Name = $_GET['Name'];
     $Email = $_GET['Email'];
     //$DOB = $_GET['DOB'];
     $Phone = $_GET['Phone'];

     $to      = 'nameyour174@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Fake sendmail test';
      $message = 'If we can read this, it means that our fake Sendmail works';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@sunkingbdltd.com';


          //Creating sql query


         $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Name='$Name' AND Email='$Email' AND Phone='$Phone'";

      //importing dbConnect.php script 
         require_once('dbConnect.php');

         //executing query
           $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

     //fetching result
      $check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

         //if we got some result  

         if(isset($check)){
      //displaying success 
      echo "success";

     if(mail($Email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
       echo 'Email sent successfully!';
       } else {
          die('Failure: Email was not sent!');
      }

        }else{
          //displaying failure
             echo "failure";
              }
           mysqli_close($con);
            }

      ?>
   ```

Comment: what mail-server are you using?

Comment: You're going to the effort of loading [PHPmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), then not using it!

Comment: Your PHP code is very vulnerable to sql injection. You really need to validate input before you use it and/or use prepared statements to separate data from code in your SQL. Maybe this conveys the message better: https://xkcd.com/327/